# Why am getting unexpected redirect (302) error when saving the data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, http-status-code-302, inertiajs

In my application, I am getting the error 302 when trying to save the data. I am posting my codes here, please someone look into this and help me.

**HolidayAdd.vue**

```
    <template>
    <layout>
        <div class="container">
            <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                    <input id="fname" type="text" class="form-control" name="ftname" placeholder="Enter your First Name" v-model="holiday.fname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                    <input id="lname" type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" v-model="holiday.lname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sdate">Start Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="sdate" v-model="holiday.sdate" id="sdate">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="edate">End Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="edate" v-model="holiday.edate" id="edate">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-info">Apply</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </layout>
</template>

<script>
import Layout from './../../Shared/Layout'
export default {
    components: {
        Layout
    },
    data() {
        return {
            holiday: {
                fname: '',
                lname: '',
                sdate: '',
                edate: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async handleSubmit() {
            let response = await this.$inertia.post('/holiday', this.holiday)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**HolidayController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $holiday = $request->validate([
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'startdate' => 'required',
            'enddate' => 'required'
        ]);

        Holiday::create($holiday);

        return redirect()->route('holiday.index');
    }
```

**web.php**

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::resource('holiday', 'HolidayController');
 });
```

As far as I know, there is no error, then why I am getting a 302 error here?

Comment: 302 is not an error code, it's a temporary redirect code caused by `return redirect()->route('holiday.index');`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the validation at your store action. you need to change

```
holiday: {
            fname: '',
            lname: '',
            sdate: '',
            edate: ''
        }
```

to

```
holiday: {
            'firstname' : '',
            'lastname' : '',
            'startdate' : '',
            'enddate' : ''
        }
```

and then change v-model to the new names. then you need to do some validation in your front-end.also you shouldn't return a redirect response if request is ajax.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I changed as your answer and now the data is being saved in database and redirecting to the expected page. But still, it throws the 302 error code. Is this because of store and index having the same URI Middleware?

Comment: you shouldn't return a redirect response if request is ajax. you can return an json that may contain a success message so you can use it in the frontend.